# rally sdk2 cardboard limit columns showing

Tags: rally

I want to limit what some users see in the kanban board. So devs to Accepted, BAs a ToDo and released. I tried this

```
            Ext.define('CustomApp', {
            extend: 'Rally.app.App',

            launch: function() {
                var cardBoardConfig = {
                    xtype: 'KanbanCardBoard',
                    cardConfig: { xtype: 'KanBanCard'},
                    types: ['User Story', 'Defect'],
                    attribute: "KanbanState",
                    storeConfig:{
                        filters: [{
                            property: 'KanbanState',
                            operator: '<',
                            value: 'Released'
                        }],
                    },
                    listeners: {
                        columnsretrieved: this._columnsretrieved,
                    }
                };

                this.add(cardBoardConfig);
            },
            _columnsretrieved: function(firstObj, retrievedColumns) { retrievedColumns = retrievedColumns.slice(2,8);} //remove first 2 and last one
        });
```

and then this

```
            Ext.define('Rally.ui.cardboard.KanbanCardBoard', {
            extend: 'Rally.ui.cardboard.CardBoard',
            alias: 'widget.KanbanCardBoard',
            _renderColumns: function() {
                    this.columnDefinitions.slice(2, 8); //remove first 2 and last one

                    if (this.columnDefinitions.length) {
                        this.add(this.columnDefinitions);
                        this.columnDefinitions[0].addCls("firstColumn");
                        this.columnDefinitions[this.columnDefinitions.length - 1].addCls("lastColumn");
                        this.showMask(this.maskMsg || 'Loading...');
                    }
            }
        });
```

but I can't limit the columns being displayed. All the columns are still showing even if i slice them away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The board also takes a [columns config](http://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p5/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.cardboard.CardBoard-cfg-columns) which allows you to specify the exact columns you'd like displayed.  By default if no columns are specified it will just show one column for each value of the specified attribute.

Comment: Example:

                         columns : [
                         {
                             xtype: 'rallykanbancolumn',
                             displayValue: 'Dev Ready',
                             value: 'Dev Ready'
                         },